# Unable to access my component through path specified in my route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { LoginComponent } from './component/login/login';
import { TodoComponent } from './component/todo/todo';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/"><LoginComponent /></Route> 
        <Route path="/todo"><TodoComponent /></Route> // Rendering my todoComponent  
    </Switch>
</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm trying to render Todocomponent on /todo path but unable to render. On going to that path 
I get Cannot GET /todo.

Comment: Are you sure that todo.js is located inside this folder "./component/todo/" ? folder 'component' must be in the same level as your working file.

Comment: Yes it's in same folder. I tried to reverse the path I was getting todoComponent on path '/'. But again not getting loginComponent on '/todo' path.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put / path component at last of all routes

```
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


    export function App(){    
         return (<Router>
            <Switch>               
                <Route path="/todo" component={TodoComponent} /> 
                <Route path="/" component={LoginComponent} /> 
            </Switch>
        </Router>);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still getting same error(cannot get '/todo')

Comment: hey try to put login component after todo its working I tried https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hawking-4qgob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208247/discussion-between-saurav-ranjan-and-niks).